# ANDROID : create a WebView when clicking a Button

Tags: android, android-layout, android-webview, android-xml, android-button

> I'm trying to add this WebView to onClick function of a button but,
>   WebView is always there before even click the button. I want WebView
>   appear only when clicked . can anyone tell which code I need to put to
>   get the WebView work when the button clicked .

```
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center" />
```

xml code

```
private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

private ViewPager mViewPager;
protected Button mButton;
private WebView webview;
ViewPager mHolder;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_app_home);

    Button mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.infobutton);
    mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
            webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

            String chtml = "<html>"+
                    "<style> div{height:50%; width:70%; background-color:#aaa;} body div:nth-child(2){height:20%; margin:20px; width:30%; background-color:#222;} h1{ color:red; font-size:24px;}</style>" +
                    "<body><h1>hello, webview</h1>  <div></div> <div></div> </body></html>";
            webview.loadData(chtml, "text/html",  "UTF-8");

        }
    });
```

java code

Comment: Tried making webview's visibility `GONE` in your xml file and make it visible on button click ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**finally found way to add WebView to api data**

> create button

```
protected WebView eventDesctibtion;
```

> assign button to view

```
eventDesctibtion = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.corporateDescription);
        WebSettings settings= eventDesctibtion.getSettings();
        settings.setDefaultFontSize(11);
```

> load data

```
eventDesctibtion.loadData(object.getString("description"), "text/html; charset=utf-8", "UTF-8");
```

Answer (score 1):

For that you can set the visibility to GONE in the xml and then on the button click you need to set visibility of the webview to VISIBLE.

Answer (score 1):

```
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/web"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center" />
```

make this us layout don't forget to add 
**android:visibility="invisible"**

**in java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

 WebView web;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fgfg);
    Button bt = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
     web =(WebView)findViewById(R.id.web);
    bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            web.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            startWebView("http://www.youtube.com");
        }
    });
}
```

inside button click

Comment: I added when I add  webview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
 inside java code app clashes

Comment: thanks for answer, but I need to add a custom web page, not a link .. and if I add set visible the app structs.

Comment: hi, If you can check this also thank you , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42050789/android-adding-searchview-inside-a-listview-with-custom-adaptor?noredirect=1#comment71422046_42050789

Comment: if you can be more specific may be i can help

Comment: you have given answer to go to a web url what i want is to go to a custom url which I create inside code . if you can please check