# Elements in Relative Layout showing differently when the app runs

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-xml, android-search

I have a `ListView` created inside a fragment, and it has a search filter, the problem is XML layout showing fine in android studio but when running in the emulator or phone it's showing differently (not properly as I aligned) and also when I click the `SearchView` it goes under the tab navigation. Can anyone tell how to fix this?

[image: this is how it looks in android studio]

[image: image is on top and the lsitview is under it and the search is under the tabs]

This is the fragment:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SearchView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.parse.FindCallback;
import com.parse.ParseException;
import com.parse.ParseFile;
import com.parse.ParseObject;
import com.parse.ParseQuery;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Individuals extends android.support.v4.app.ListFragment
        implements FindCallback<ParseObject> {

    private List<ParseObject> mOrganization = new ArrayList<ParseObject>();
    SearchView sv;
    IndividualsAdaptor adaptor;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.individuals, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle b) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, b);
        sv = (SearchView) view.findViewById(R.id.ser1);
        adaptor = new IndividualsAdaptor(getActivity(), mOrganization);
        setListAdapter(adaptor);
        ParseQuery.getQuery("_User").findInBackground(this);

        sv.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String text) {
                return false;
            }
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String text) {
                adaptor.getFilter().filter(text);
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void done(List<ParseObject> scoreList, ParseException e) {
        if (e == null) {
            Log.d("score", "Retrieved " + scoreList.size() + " _User");
            mOrganization.clear();
            mOrganization.addAll(scoreList);
            ((IndividualsAdaptor) getListAdapter()).updateBackupList(mOrganization);
            ((IndividualsAdaptor) getListAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
        } else {
            Log.d("score", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

This is the adapter:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Filter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.parse.ParseObject;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class IndividualsAdaptor extends ArrayAdapter {

        protected Context mContext;
        // Code for Custom Filter.
        protected List mBackupList = new ArrayList();

        public IndividualsAdaptor(Context context, List status) {
            super(context, R.layout.t3, status);
            mContext = context;
            // Code for Custom Filter.
            mBackupList.addAll(status);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder holder;

            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
                StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
                StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
            }

            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.t3, null);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.usernameHomepage = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.fname);
                holder.statusHomepage = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lname);
                holder.pposition = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.idposition);
                holder.orgName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.organizationname);
                holder.logo = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            ParseObject statusObject = (ParseObject) getItem(position);
            // title
            String username = statusObject.getString("firstname");
            holder.usernameHomepage.setText(username);
            // content
            String status = statusObject.getString("lastname");
            holder.statusHomepage.setText(status);
            // content
            String positions = statusObject.getString("position");
            holder.pposition.setText(positions);
            // content
            String org = statusObject.getString("organizationName");
            holder.orgName.setText(org);
            // logo
            URL url = null;
            Bitmap bmp = null;
            try {
                url = new URL("img hosting location" + statusObject.getString("image"));
                bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            }catch (IOException e) {
            }
            holder.logo.setImageBitmap(bmp);
            Picasso.with(mContext)
                    .load(String.valueOf(url))
                    .into(((ImageView) convertView
                            .findViewById(R.id.imageView)));

            return convertView;
        }

        public static class ViewHolder {
            TextView usernameHomepage;
            TextView statusHomepage;
            TextView orgName;
            TextView pposition;
            ImageView logo;
        }

        // Code for Custom Filter.
        @Override
        public Filter getFilter() {return new Filter(){
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {
                String queryString = charSequence.toString().toLowerCase();
                List<ParseObject> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
                ParseObject tmpItem;
                String tmpUsername, tmpStatus, tmpPositions, tmpOrg;
                for(int i=0; i<mBackupList.size(); i++){
                    tmpItem = (ParseObject) mBackupList.get(i);
                    tmpUsername = tmpItem.getString("firstname").toLowerCase();
                    tmpStatus = tmpItem.getString("lastname").toLowerCase();
                    tmpPositions = tmpItem.getString("position").toLowerCase();
                    tmpOrg = tmpItem.getString("organizationName").toLowerCase();
                    // The matching condition
                    if(tmpUsername.contains(queryString)||tmpStatus.contains(queryString)||
                            tmpPositions.contains(queryString)||tmpOrg.contains(queryString)){
                        filteredList.add(tmpItem);
                    }
                }
                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                filterResults.count = filteredList.size();
                filterResults.values = filteredList;
                return filterResults;
            }
            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, Filter.FilterResults filterResults) {
                clear();
                addAll((List<ParseObject>) filterResults.values);
            }
        };}

        public void updateBackupList(List newList){
            mBackupList.clear();
            mBackupList.addAll(newList);
        }
    }
```

The `ListView` layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    android:paddingRight="0dp">

    <TextView android:id="@id/android:empty"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="335dp"
        android:text="No data"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/android:list"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/android:list" />

    <SearchView
        android:id="@+id/ser1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:queryHint="Search.."
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/android:empty"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
    </SearchView>

    <ListView android:id="@id/android:list"
              android:layout_width="263dp"
              android:layout_height="241dp"
              android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
              android:layout_below="@+id/android:empty"
              android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
              android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
              android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
              android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/individuals_img"
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/android:empty"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/android:empty"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The item layout for the `ListView`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="14dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
        />
    <!--  img  -->


    <TextView
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/organizationname"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/idposition"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/idposition"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/idposition"
        android:paddingTop="10px" />


    <TextView
        android:text="yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/idposition"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/fname"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/fname"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/fname" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fname"
        android:text="Name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif" />

    <TextView
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/lname"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_above="@+id/idposition"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/organizationname"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/organizationname" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Main activity layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="app.com.anew.fbcapplication.AppHome">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <Button
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:background="@drawable/nav"
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_weight="1"

                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                tools:paddingLeft="25dp"
                tools:layout_marginLeft="20dp" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:background="@drawable/i"
                android:id="@+id/button"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

            <ImageView
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/logo"
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                tools:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_width="280dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/button"
                android:layout_height="50dp" />

        </RelativeLayout>


        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabTextAppearance="@style/TabTextAppearance"
            />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you can include image from your layout editor and actual image which you're seeing.

Comment: @Jabbar_Jigariyo I added the screen shot , but the ListView is only showing between image and the tab , and its under the tab and also the SearchView but it is showing perfectly in the android studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get error when trying your ListView (I think that it is individuals.xml), e.g. TextView android:id="@id/android:empty" has an attribute android:layout_below="@+id/button3" but I can't find button3 in your layout.

This may be the layout that you want, individuals.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/individuals_img"
    android:src="@drawable/individuals_img"
    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>

<SearchView
    android:id="@+id/ser1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:queryHint="Search.."
    android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView3"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/imageView3" >
</SearchView>

<TextView android:id="@id/android:empty"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="No data"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ser1" />

<ListView android:id="@id/android:list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ser1" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

If this is not what you are looking for, please also show what your layout looks like in Android Studio layout editor. Hope it help :)

Comment: I added the scren shot to  I tried this code , then searchview and image all disapears. ? is it bcoz Iam using Relative Layout ?

Comment: Edited the answer. Please check if this is close to what you want. Problem for the layout that you post: other views relative to the empty view. Therefore when the list is not empty, the layout will be different from what you see. You can test by setting the empty view visibility to GONE. In addition, in the screen shot of your layout, the search view id is set as: searchUserTextField, that does not match the code you posted.

Comment: thanks. I'll try . if you don't mind can you give your e-mail id please .? @I_A_Mok

Comment: RelativeLayout not working i tried LinearLayout its working.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42344362/creating-webview-for-a-listview-item-click   @I_A_Mok  please check this if you can.